# condicionar una opcion dentro del codigo

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo un código pero de acuerdo a una condición, le agrego o le quito una un trozo, el problema es que no se como hacerlo, si  "attachments" trae algo debería aparecer dentro del message, pero sino, no debería, si alguien puede de antemano gracias, aquí el código:

```
if (options.attachments != undefined) {
    var attachment = FS.readFileSync('/archivo.pdf').toString("base64");

    var message = {
        to: options.to,
        from: 'Hola ',
        subject: options.subject,

        html: templateHtml,
        attachments: [
            {
                content: attachment,
                filename: "terminosCondicones.pdf",
                type: "application/pdf",
                disposition: "attachment"
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

Quisiera agregar o quitar este trozo de código:

```
   attachments: [
            {
                content: attachment,
                filename: "terminosCondicones.pdf",
                type: "application/pdf",
                disposition: "attachment"
            }
        ]
```

el problema es que no he podido, de antemano gracias....

Comment: Y si creas un ternario donde validez el largo de _attachments_ y en caso que sea menor o igual a 0, lo devuelves como arreglo vacío

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que los campos `to`, `from`, `subject`y `html` son siempre fijos, te recomendaría primero rellenar esa estructura (en el ejemplo autoejecutable, la variable `message`). Después, en función de esa lógica (el if que comprueba si hay adjuntos o no), añadiría o no a esa estructura base la parte correspondiente de `attachments`.

```js
// Puedes utilizar esta variable para simular si hay o no attachments
const hasAttachment = true;

// Estructura básica, campos que irán si o si
let message = {
  to: 'to',
  from: 'Hola ',
  subject: 'subject',
  html: 'tplHtml',
};

// En función de la condición, si es verdadera, añadimos la parte de los attachments
if(hasAttachment) {
  const attachment = 'contenido del fichero';
  message.attachments = [
   {
     content: attachment,
     filename: "terminosCondicones.pdf",
     type: "application/pdf",
     disposition: "attachment"
   }
  ];
}

console.log('Mensaje: ', message);
```

Espero que te sirva. Cualquier duda, puedes utilizar los comentarios.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me funciono perfecto, Gracias por tu tiempo, bendiciones